# I can't install matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.2]
                python: yes [3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015,
                        01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.11.1]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.5.3]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2016.6.1]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\matplotlib\

I have tried uninstalling and installing again the pip, but it did not work. I do not know what to do. :(
If you can comment in spanish would help me a lot, my English is not so good, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I installed matplotlib with the .whl file and it worked for me. I got it from this website http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib. Download the right .whl package ( i.e If you have Python 3.5.1 64 bit download matplotlib-2.0.0b3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl) Then go to File Explorer and go to the folder where you downloaded the .whl file. On file explorer click File -> open command prompt -> open as adminstrator. Then type this

```
pip install (fileName.whl)
```

If it says that pip is not found then go to the place where you downloaded python in file explorer. Go to the scripts folder and open it there. You can copy and paste the .whl file in the scripts folder. Then type the pip install command again. After that's done you can check if it works by going to IDLE and try importing it

```
import matplotlib
```

if it runs that means you installed it correctly. That is the only way I know to install matplotlib so sorry if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried, but not work, the problem is i can't upgrade pip to 8.1.2, python supposedly installed, but in the console i look pip 7.1.0, too can't install freetype and libpng manually but for pip i can't, too tried upgrate pip but I paragraph appears a huge red

Comment: Try this. Go to control panel -> uninstall a program -> and click python. Then click Uninstall/Change. A screen is supposed to popup that says Uninstall / Repair. Click repair. That should repair python and try to do it again. I've never had a problem with pip before so that is my only solution to that, sorry :(.  Edit: Oh try this link https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1299